# How to read csv file in string format in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, ssis

The entire workflow is that I need to read a `csv` file located at a path, then do some modifications in the data and then load the data into specific tables  through C#. The C# code is running inside `MSBI SSIS` package script.

I am using .Net `StreamReader` to read the data from the file path.

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"filepath"));
```

This works very fine but after that I'm unable to convert the `StreamReader` output to string format for some complex data modification in string.

Is there any direct type casting that I can use here? Any alternate solutions are also welcome.

Comment: System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Path");

Comment: Your question header and the body doesn't match! What is the problem you are facing, precisely?

Comment: @ArghyaC, The StreamReader returns a var value while WebClient.DownloadString(URI) returns a string. The code for the data modification is done according to string. I need to convert the StreamReader var into string so that I can use the rest of my code. Type casting is not working here.

Comment: @MajkeloDev: Works fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"filepath"));
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');

    //Do processing here, modify values and add to tables etc
}
```

the values object will then be an array of values in order of the csv.

You can then access using values[0], values[1], values[n] etc.  Do your processing on the individual values and add to tables record by record.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
 I have tried this but the problem here are two: For csv with multiple rows and if they are embedded in quotes.(as there is an address field and that may contain ','). The other one is the values array will be of type 'var'. That will not allow me to make the modifications in the data.

Comment: You could split on on '"' first and then split the resulting array values based on ",".  And to get around the issue with var, just cast to whatever you need. value.ToString() or int32.TryParse() will come in handy.  What data type do you need from the data?

And I'm pretty sure String.Split gives an array of String not var.